# Add SVG tooltip to stroke on <circle />

Tags: svg

I am creating a donut chart with svg, and I would like to have tooltips on hover of the donut rings. I am building the donut like this:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card {
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    padding: 2em;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
}

.pie-center {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle1 {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: teal;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 30 70;    
}

.circle2 {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: orangered;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 45 55;
    stroke-dashoffset: -30;
    
}

.circle3 {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: orchid;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 20 80;
    stroke-dashoffset: -75;
}

.circle4 {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: yellowgreen;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 5 95;
    stroke-dashoffset: -95;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <svg class="pie-center" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <circle class="circle1" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" />
                    <circle class="circle2" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" />
                    <circle class="circle3" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" />
                    <circle class="circle4" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know that I can use the `<set />` tag to capture mouse events, and I can use those to create a tooltip. The problem is each section of the donut ring is actually a circle, and the `stroke` property on the circle is the part I actually want to capture the hover event for.

Therefore, when I try to add hover actions to my circles I don't get desired results.

This is what I have tried (just turning the donut section red on hover to simulate capturing the event for adding a tooltip):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card {
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    padding: 2em;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
}

.pie-center {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle1 {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: teal;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 30 70;
}

.circle2 {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: orangered;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 45 55;
    animation: dash3 1s ease 0s 1 forwards;
    stroke-dashoffset: -30;
}

.circle3 {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: orchid;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 20 80;
    animation: dash2 1s ease 0s 1 forwards;
    stroke-dashoffset: -75;
}

.circle4 {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: yellowgreen;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 5 95;
    animation: dash 1s ease 0s 1 forwards;
    stroke-dashoffset: -95;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card new">
                <svg class="pie-center" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <circle class="circle1" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" >
                        <set attributeName='stroke' from='teal' to='red' begin='mouseover' end='mouseout' />
                    </circle>
                    <circle class="circle2" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" >
                        <set attributeName='stroke' from='orangered' to='red' begin='mouseover' end='mouseout' />
                    </circle>
                    <circle class="circle3" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" >
                        <set attributeName='stroke' from='orchid' to='red' begin='mouseover' end='mouseout' />
                    </circle>
                    <circle class="circle4" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" >
                        <set attributeName='stroke' from='yellowgreen' to='red' begin='mouseover' end='mouseout' />
                    </circle>
                </svg>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is: **Is there any way to capture hover events on the circle strokes? Or is there another way to create a donut chart, using say `<path />` or some other svg element that will better support the hover events?**

I would like to not use third party libraries if possible (no D3, or chart.js).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use fill: none rather than fill: transparent so that the fill does not react. In fact there's really no good reason to use fill: transparent ever.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card {
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    padding: 2em;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
}

.pie-center {
    background: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle1 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: teal;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 30 70;
}

.circle2 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: orangered;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 45 55;
    animation: dash3 1s ease 0s 1 forwards;
    stroke-dashoffset: -30;
}

.circle3 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: orchid;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 20 80;
    animation: dash2 1s ease 0s 1 forwards;
    stroke-dashoffset: -75;
}

.circle4 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: yellowgreen;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 5 95;
    animation: dash 1s ease 0s 1 forwards;
    stroke-dashoffset: -95;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card new">
                <svg class="pie-center" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <circle class="circle1" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" >
                        <set attributeName='stroke' from='teal' to='red' begin='mouseover' end='mouseout' />
                    </circle>
                    <circle class="circle2" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" >
                        <set attributeName='stroke' from='orangered' to='red' begin='mouseover' end='mouseout' />
                    </circle>
                    <circle class="circle3" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" >
                        <set attributeName='stroke' from='orchid' to='red' begin='mouseover' end='mouseout' />
                    </circle>
                    <circle class="circle4" r="15.915494309" cx="16" cy="16" >
                        <set attributeName='stroke' from='yellowgreen' to='red' begin='mouseover' end='mouseout' />
                    </circle>
                </svg>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was going down the rabbit hole of trying to recreate this using paths (which is way more difficult). I would have never known to use `fill: none` rather than `fill: transparent`. Thank you sir.

Comment: I was having the same problem and just read this. Thanks Robert Longson this was really helpful.